# Glossary Package is Not Working

Tags: glossaries

I am trying to produce a glossary at the end of my book. However, apparently glossary package is not working. A minimal example is given below:

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openany]{book}
   \usepackage{tocbibind}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}
   \usepackage{geometry}
   \geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}
   \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
   \usepackage[xindy]{glossaries} 
   \input{glossary}
   \makeglossaries
   \usepackage{acro}
   \begin{document}
   \author{Ahmed Arif}
   \title{Thesis Title}
   \date{December 2016}
   \renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}

   \frontmatter
   \maketitle
   \tableofcontents
   \listoftables
   \listoffigures
   \printacronyms[name= List of Acronyms,sort=true,heading=chapter*]
   \mainmatter
   \chapter{Introduction}
    This is introduction chapter.
    \appendix
         \appendixpage
         \noappendicestocpagenum
         \addappheadtotoc
         \chapter{An Appendix}
    \printglossaries
    \end{document}
```

The glossary entry is given below:

```
   \newglossaryentry{abs}{%
name={Asset-Backed Securities},%
description={These are the securities backed by assets.}}
```

However, nothing is produced at the end of the document. Please help to rectify this issue.

Comment: Glossary entries are only printed if they are actually used with a `\gls` or similar command or if `\glsaddall` is given. By the way, why are you using the `acro` package? The `glossaries` package can also do acronyms.

Comment: Even if I add the command `\glsaddall` before `\printglossaries`, nothing is printed.

Comment: Did you run `latex` --> `makeglossaries` --> `latex`? Or `xindy` instead of `makeglossaries`?

Comment: @PietvanOostrum I did not understand what you mean. I already place `\makeglossaries` in preamble and then running `latex` after  putting `\printglossaries` at the end.

Comment: OK, I'll explain. After you have run (pdf)latex on your file, the raw glossary is put in a `.glo` file. Let's say your LaTeX file is called `mypaper.tex`. Then there will be a file `mypaper.glo` containing information about the glossary entries. However, this file must be sorted and processed to a file `mypaper.gls` which contains the glossary as it will be put in your paper. This file is created by a program `makeglossaries`. So this is an external program. You run, from a command line, or by means of your editor/IDE the command `makeglossaries mypaper`. After that you run LaTeX again.